# What's the point of observer pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm currently learning Java and it's quite interesting but something really bugs me. I understand how to use the observer pattern but I can't find any real use for it. I've obviously saw some examples but i've found that it would make the code more complicated and that there were many simpler way to do those stuff.

So if someone has a simple explanation/example where the Observer pattern would really have an utility, I would appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.  Most GUIs are built this way.  The pattern finds its way into other architectures as well, like asynchronous messaging, etc.

Comment: Please list some of the "_many simpler ways_" you refer to.

Answer (score 3):

You're posting a question on Stack Overflow, and we all getting notified that a question has been posted. That is observer pattern.

Comment: Are we notified? I don't know about you, but I had to check the stackoverflow page to see this question, so rather than subscribing to a subject, and then being notified proactively, I actually had to *poll* stackoverflow for updates. That's not the observer pattern.

Comment: @meriton Web sockets if you got 'em.

Comment: We are notified like "2 new questions on" something like tha. It even changes our browser's title bar. And then we can pull those new questions.
It is not loading those questions by default, but letting us know that new questions are posted.

Comment: Also the person asking the question gets notifications when someone answers

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a good and simple example, let's imagine operating systems were written in Java. We would then have a class `Mouse`, and many applications that want to respond to mouse clicks.

A naive approach would be for each application to constantly ask the mouse whether the mouse button is currently pressed:

```
class MyApplication {
    void run() {
        for (;;) {
            if (Mouse.isLeftButtonDown()) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has the disadvantage that if the mouse button is not pressed, we have a thread that constantly executes that loop. This is particularly bad if every application did this. Your CPU would constantly be busy checking the mouse, needlessly consuming energy, and causing other processes and programs to slow down. A first improvement would be to add a short sleep delay into the loop:

```
class MyApplication {
    Mouse mouse;

    void run() {
        for (;;) {
            if (mouse.isLeftButtonDown()) {
                // do something
            }
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```

This would save cpu time, but if the mouse button is down less than 50 ms (or another thread by a badly programmed application has hogged the cpu, preventing our thread from running), the application might not notice the click.

These issues can neatly be avoided by using the observer pattern, with the mouse as subject, and the various applications (or windows) as listeners:

```
class MyApplication implements MouseListener {
    MyApplication() {
        Mouse.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Override onLeftClick() {
        // do something
    }

    void close() {
        Mouse.unsubscribe(this);
    }
}
```

Granted, by itself, this has merely moved the problem of detecting mouse clicks from the application to the operating system. The operating system might still have a dedicated click watching thread (which would already be much more resource friendly than a click watching thread for every application). But the operating system can in turn use the observer pattern to delegate watching for clicks to the actual hardware, by installing an event listener for a [hardware interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt). With that solution, watching for clicks is done by a simple circuit in the mouse itself, which can detect mouse clicks with very high fidelity, without occupying the cpu with needless busy work.

In short, something as basic as reliably detecting mouse clicks would not be accomplished with the reliability and efficiency we are accustomed to, were it not for the insight that it can be more convenient to be notified of an event than constantly checking whether an event occurred ourselves.